# How to get original version of the DataFrame in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

While I was dealing with a DataFrame, it happend that I changed the values of one column.
Then, I realised that it affected my DataFrame.

```
print(df) #Before applying the change

    A   B
0   3   5
1   9   6
2   4   7

print(df) #After applying the change

    A   B
0   3   0
1   9   0
2   4   0
```

Then, I used the method (df._is_view) to see if my df is a view or a copy and as a result the output is : Flase.

So, is there a way to get my original DataFrame (Before I made the change).

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Going to need to see some code to fix this.

Comment: @EdekiOkoh I edited the post. I wish it's clear now.

Comment: Easiest thing to do is to use something like df2 = df.copy() and then do the changes using df2 while leaving the original df unchanged.

Comment: this should be done before I  made any changes! my dataset contains hundreds of rows. what I wanted to know is if there is any way to delete changes and get the first df I created?

Comment: Depends on the code you used to make that change. Based on the info given it is not possible to know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer is no. Copied dataframes don't maintain pointers to the source dataframes they are copies of.

If your dataframe is a copy of an object with its own identifier, then the data will of course still be preserved there:

```py
>>> df_orig = pd.DataFrame({'A': [3, 9, 4], 'B': [5, 6, 7]})
>>> df = df_orig.copy()
>>> df['B'] = 0
>>> df._is_view
False
```

In this case, `df_orig` will still have your data. But if you don't have a variable pointing to the data, you're out of luck. Hope this helps!